# Lerna boostrap fails with npm ERR! code E401

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, monorepo, lerna

whenever i'm running Lerna bootstrap on Jenkins its fails with error, but passes on local machine.

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
```

**Package.json on main folder**

```
"scripts":{
  "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap --loglevel verbose",
  "publish-packages": "lerna publish --skip-git",
  "clean": "lerna clean"
},
"dependencies": {
  "lerna": "^5.0.0"
}
```

**lerna.json**

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "npmClientArgs": [
    "--strict-ssl=false",
    "--always-auth=true"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

**running commands**

```
npm i
npm run bootstrap
```

**npm i - passes but "npm run bootstrap" fails.**

**I've tried multiple options like**

1. in .npmrc added credentials for my-repo

   > //my-repo-url:8081/nexus/repository/npm-repo/:_password=##base-64-encoded-password##
   > //my-repo-url:8081/nexus/repository/npm-repo/:username=##usernamr##
2. in added in .npmrc _auth=##base-64-encoded-username-and-password##
3. added or removed "--always-auth=true" & "--strict-ssl" from "npmClientArgs" in lerna.json

**Versions**

1. node v14.17.0
2. npm  6.14.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option#1**

1. I resolved by, adding "_auth" in lerna.json -> npmClientArgs.I
   Copied _auth value from .npmrc and added in "npmClientArgs"
2. You can also generate authToken and use it here

> ```
> {
>   "packages": [
>     "packages/*"
>   ],
>   "npmClientArgs": [
>     "--strict-ssl=false",
>     "--always-auth=true",
>     "--_auth=AUTH-KEY"
>   ],
>   "version": "independent"
> }
> ```

**Option#2**

1. During build, you can recursively copy .npmrc in all "**packages/***" folder